# Retrieving values column wise from database using jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to retrieve data from database column wise.  Say if I have Column 'a'  then I want all values of that column and then I have another column say 'b'  then I want to get all values of that column  and so on for all columns.

My code is giving me row wise value.  First it will retrieve data from first row and then second and so on.  My code is as follows.

```
while (rs.next()) {
 for(inti=1;i<=rsMetaData.getColumnCount();i++) {
 System.out.println(rs.getString(i)); 
}
 }
```

Please suggest how to get all values of first column then second and so on.

Comment: instead of printing append each value of each column to a List

Comment: @slippsryseal while Iterating over result set I am not getting any option to iterate over column 1 then column 2 and so on every time it's giving row wise results

Comment: @scary it would be very helpful if you can suggest an example code

Comment: see my answer below for some rough workings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate Data Row wise and convert to Column wise. Something Like this :

```
        ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table");
        ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
        Map<String, List<Object>> resultMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            for(int i=1;i<=rsMetaData.getColumnCount();i++) {
                String strColumnName = rsMetaData.getColumnName(i);
                Object columnValue = rs.getObject(i);
                if(resultMap.containsKey(strColumnName)){
                    resultMap.get(strColumnName).add(columnValue);
                }else{
                    List<Object> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
                    resultList.add(columnValue);
                    resultMap.put(strColumnName,resultList);
                }
            }
        }
        // Iterate Data Column Wise
        for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, List<Object>>> iterator = resultMap.entrySet().iterator();iterator.hasNext();){
            Map.Entry<String, List<Object>> entry = iterator.next();
            System.out.println("Column Name: "+entry.getKey());
            System.out.println("Column Values: "+entry.getValue());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A more flexible solution might use a `HashMap` instead of a `List`. This way you can store the column names as keys, which makes retrieving values easier and more transparent.

```
//declare a HashMap

Map<String,Object> hMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    public void populateColumns(ResultSet rs) { 
            try{  
                    while(rs.next()){           
            for (int i=1;i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++) { 
                    Object obj=rs.getObject(i); //get the value for whatever column the result has   
                    hMap.put(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), obj); 
                } }
            }catch (Exception e) { 
            //handle the exception
            } 
        }
```

Note that if you want special handling for some database types /Java types, you can use the `instanceof` operator.

```
for (int i=1;i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();i++) { 
            Object obj=rs.getObject(i); /
            if(obj instanceof String) //if obj is a String
                hMap.put(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), new String(((String)obj).getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8"));
            else //for every other objects
                hMap.put(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), obj);
```

UPDATE:

To get the output like you want try this

```
public void populateColumns(ResultSet rs) {
            List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
            int colCount;
            try{   
            while(rs.next()){
            colCount =  rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();      
            for (int i=1;i<=colCount;i++) { 
                    Object obj=rs.getObject(i); //get the value for whatever column the result has   
                    list.add(obj); 
                } 
            }
            }catch (Exception e) { 
            //handle the exception
            } 

            //
            List<Object> sortedByCol = new ArrayList<Object>();

            for(int j=0; j<colCount;j++){
            for(int i=j; i<list.size(); i+=colCount){

            sortedByCol.add(list.get(i));
            }

        }
```

For input like

```
     col a    col b   col c

1 row   1         2       3
2 row   1         2       3
```

your output list (sortedByCol) will have

```
1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3
```

Comment: Sir I tried this it is giving only some wise values

Comment: What do mean by wise values? Update your original post.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.. It is giving only row wise values means like this suppose I have three columns a, b and c and their values for first and second rows are as follows 1,2,3 and 1,2,3.. I want first values of column a that is 1,1 and then for second column 2,2 and so on..but with result set I am getting only row wise that is 1,2,3 and 1,2,3

Answer (score -1):

have comma delimitered String value for each column which is in an ArraList

Something like (Sorry not in front of a computer)

```
ArrayList<String> columnValList = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
   for(inti=0;i<rsMetaData.getColumnCount();i++) {
       // get element for this col - create if doesnt exist
       String cols = columnValList.get (i);   // error checking needed
       cols = cols + "," + rs.getString (i + 1);
       // put it back
       columnValList.set (i, cols);
   }
}
```

after this you will have element(0) containing all values for the first columns etc